# Report running in SQL Developer and Report Builder but not on the server

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have created a report and tested it in Report Builder 3.0 it works fine, however when I place it on the report server for access to the staff the report does not run.

I can see the parameters but when I click 'Run Report' I get nothing, no errors, just a blank report.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using a shared datasource? If so is the datasource on the server the same as in your dev environment? If not, there could just be no data for the report to display. I think the default setting is to not overwrite datasources, so when you deploy your report it does not update the datasource the report references on the server.

Comment: The staff is using IE and not Chrome, right?

Comment: Yes I was using a shared datasource, it all matched, I've done around 30 reports these past few weeks and all work beautifully. 

They're using IE.


I found a work around to the issue, it turns out some of the data in one parameter was 'dirty' linking nowhere and having zero contextual meaning. I changed it to a wildcard '%%' it works as required but not my favourite solution. Thanks for your time.